# How to solve the following error running rmcorr in R: Error in isa(Participant, "character") : could not find function "isa"

Tags: r, correlation

I have the data in long format, with subject (numbered 1 to 124), Day, measure1, and measure2. There are about 14 repeating measures per subject. I want to run rmcorr to see if there is a correlation between measure1 and measure2 across all subjects. I used the code:

```
rmcorr(participant, measure1, measure2, data)
```

I get:

```
Error in isa(Participant, "character") : could not find function "isa"
```

I have used the same syntax before without any errors arising!

Comment: `rmcorr` is not in the base library as far as I know. You should identify where this function is available. Also, it is already recommended to make a question reproducible. Please provide sample data (typically using `dput`) and make a script that produces the error in question.

Comment: You need to load the libraries corresponding to the missing functions, notably `library(rmcorr)`

Comment: @Basti loaded the rmcorr library prior to running the syntax, yet the error still emerged.

Comment: Maybe you could try to update the package

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen this error with older versions of R and strangely with 4.0.4, but only in Linux. I would try updating R. Hopefully that works!

Answer (score 0):

The isa() function is a function in the base library (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/class.html), which is not part of all versions of R (use "?class()" to see if your version includes it).

In my case it worked to replace it with the "is()"-function, which does (in most cases, see documentation) pretty much the same. Just do

```
library(rmcorr)
isa = is
rmcorr(your input)
```

and you will be fine.

Best regards,

JF